# What should it look like when your SQL servers are properly licensed?

Tags: sql-server

New job, going through my server inventory. I've been using this script to get the version & licensing:

```
select @@version as version, 
SERVERPROPERTY('LicenseType') as licenseType, 
SERVERPROPERTY('NumLicenses') as NumLicenses
```

But *all* my results are returning a disabled license, and null for the number:

```
version                                 licenseType NumLicenses
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) ...  DISABLED    NULL
```

Which has me questioning myself. Licensing isn't something I've had to deal with before. Is this query correct? Is it even possible for it to function without being properly licensed?

**question:** What should my query return if my server is properly licensed? Is there a better way to check?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing questions are off topic for this stack exchange site.

Comment: @JoeObbish Is this documented? I don't see a definitive declaration of that policy here for example https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/487/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith It's based on that meta post and seeing licensing questions closed over time. Maybe I've been interpreting it wrong. https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a1%20"license"

Comment: @JoeObbish personally I'm not a fan of licencing questions. If they are officially off topic though I would expect this to be mentioned in one of the links in the close message above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha, those will always be disabled and null, according to the [SERVERPROPERTY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql) manual page:

- LicenseType:

  > Unused. License information is not preserved or maintained by the SQL Server product. Always returns DISABLED.
- NumLicenses:

  > Unused. License information is not preserved or maintained by the SQL Server product. Always returns NULL.

The query is not correct.

Instead, I need to download Microsoft's [Assessment and Planning Toolkit (MAP)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7826).